# Changing the section and subsection font color in contents page in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, color

[image: my contents page]

I want to change the section and subsection names in my contents page on beamer. Plz help me. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 20):

Without MWE, I can only bet your table of contents is created with the command

```
\tableofcontents
```

If so, putting those two lines in your preamble should do the trick

```
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=red}
```

You can of course change "gray" and "red" to any color you like. The commands are pretty clear for themselves. One thing though : `fg` here means foreground.