# changing text color in subsection in tableofcontents in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, color

I don't have a MWE, but what I am trying to do is to change the text color of the subsection in the tableofcontents in beamer. What I have is this:

```
\section{Live Querying Approach}
         \subsection{Traversal-based approach}
         \subsection{\textcolor{blue}{Index-based approach}}
         \subsection{{\color{blue} Hybrid approach}}

%
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
```

Without the `\textcolor` in the `\subsection`, this, of course, works well, but when I use the `\textcolor` it throws an error. How do I do this?

I am aware of this [Changing the section and subsection font color in contents page in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198625/changing-the-section-and-subsection-font-color-in-contents-page-in-beamer), but that changes the color in all of the \subsections in the document -- all I want to do is to change in one case.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Will there be more subsections after the `Hybrid approach`?

Comment: No, I have three subsections and I want to highlight the last two -- the example shows two different ways  I tried, and both threw errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your question is rather tricky to answer, but maybe the following workaround is good enough:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\mypause}[1][+]{\onslide<#1>}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}

\begin{document}

\section{Live Querying Approach}
\subsection{Traversal-based approach}
\subsection{Index-based approach}
\subsection{Hybrid approach}

\begin{frame}<2>
    \setbeamercovered{%
       still covered={\opaqueness<1->{100}},
       again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
    }
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=blue}
    \let\pause\mypause
    \tableofcontents[pausesubsections]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure what you are getting (since you were not able to upload image), but in my case it only shows "Live Querying Approach" in light grey but nothing else shows.

Comment: @ozsu I am getting the section name and "Traversal-based approach" in grey and "Index-based approach" and "Hybrid approach" in bright blue.

Comment: @ozsu Do you get this strange result with exact the MWE from my answer or with you full document?

Comment: Sorry @samcarter, my error: I forgot to compile twice. Now it works. Many thanks.

Comment: @ozsu Good to hear!