# How to obtain two different section colours in TOC in beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, color

See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198625/changing-the-section-and-subsection-font-color-in-contents-page-in-beamer) :

a TOC is added to a `beamer` presentation using `\tableofcontents`.

Is it possible to set the color of only one section title in the TOC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Just in case, I am using  `beamer.cls    2021/03/19 v3.62`

Use `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{beamer}` to check.

[image: s]

```
\listfiles % look at the end of the .log file

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{Test 1: {\color{red}test 1}}
    
    \begin{frame}{Hello}        
        How are you?        
    \end{frame}

    \section{\color{red} Test 2: test 2}
    \begin{frame}{OK}   
    Bye 
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```