# How to change the color of a part of a section title in beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, color

MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1: {\color{blue}test 2}}

\begin{frame}{Hello}

How are you?

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Is it possible to change the color of part of the section title?

Using `\section{Test 1: {\color{blue}test 2}}`, I obtain the error

> `! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }.`

Comment: In `beamer` v3.42 or newer, color commands are all protected (or, robust). So, which version of `beamer` do you use?

Comment: Using   beamer.cls    2021/03/19 v3.62 your command works fine.

Comment: @SimonDispa OK, I invite you to repeat this as an answer below so I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `beamer` package and the the code will work fine.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603644/161015  using `beamer.cls 2021/03/19 v3.62`.

Use `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{beamer}` and check at the end of the .log file to get your current version.

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2021/03/19 v3.62 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty    
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
beamerbaseoptions.sty
```